# Add claims to Wso2 service provider through AdminServices

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

So i am trying to add claims to a service provider in Wso2. I have managed to create an IdentityApplication and connect it with some SSO configuration. The only problem is adding Claims to that SSO because i use those after the SSO login.

So what i have tried so far:

- I have added an SSO configuration using the `addRPServiceProvider` soap function from the `IdentitySAMLSSOConfigService`
- I have created a service provider using `createApplication` soap function from the `IdentityApplicationManagementService` and connected it to the SSO configuration i added earlier

At this point my external application connects correctly with Wso2 and do the SSO. The only thing i need is to return additional claim info with the SSO response.

I am trying to do that using the `claimConfig` part of the `createApplication` function parameters but i cant seem to make it right.

Is there somewhere some more info about how to set this up through the AdminServices? ( the official docs are not really helping
)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Using+the+Service+Provider+API) for more information on using the API. You can't add the claimConfig during the `createApplication` call as it only allows you to set the `applicationName` and `description`. Set the `claimConfig` during `updateApplication` method. The document has a sample request in `Claim configuration level parameters` section.